# Replace brackets in references with commas in Latex

Tags: reference, latex

I would like to replace the brackets of the year with commas in the references as it is the standard method in the Journal of Finance.

In the references, I have this structure; Author (2020) Title... but I would like to change it to; Author, 2020, Title...

This would be a sample bibliography:

```
@article{examplesource,
  title={Title of article},
  author={LastName1, FirstName1 and LastName2, FirstName2 and LastName3, FirstName3},
  journal={Journal of Finance},
  volume={40},
  number={1},
  pages={3--73},
  year={2005}}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber, giveninits=true, uniquelist = false, uniquename=init, isbn=false, maxcitenames=3, dashed=false, maxbibnames=999, doi=false, url=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
%\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\setlength{\bibhang}{15pt}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}
    {\ifentrytype{article}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitlecase}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}}}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journaltitle}
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
  \printfield{volume}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\UndeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}{(}{)}


\begin{document}
\textcite{examplesource} lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\\

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua \parencite{examplesource}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily you are using the `ext-authoryear` style, so you can use

- `\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}` to remove the parenthesis
- `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}` to add a comma before the year
- `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{innamebeforetitle=true} \DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}` to add a comma after the year

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber, giveninits=true, uniquelist = false, uniquename=init, isbn=false, maxcitenames=3, dashed=false, maxbibnames=999, doi=false, url=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
%\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\setlength{\bibhang}{15pt}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}
    {\ifentrytype{article}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitlecase}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{journal}{
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{journaltitle}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{journalsubtitle}}}
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journaltitle}
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}
       \printfield[journaltitlecase]{journalsubtitle}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
  \printfield{volume}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
  \printfield{eid}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\UndeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{parencite}{(}{)}

\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{innamebeforetitle=true} \DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}



\begin{document}
\textcite{knuth:ct} lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\\

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua \parencite{knuth:ct}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]